# Larger spacing around logical connectives

Tags: spacing, logic, relation-symbols

(Writing for myself, I ended up writing a rather verbose background, so you can skip directly to the *Question* below.)

## Background

TeX or LaTeX (I do not know which does what exactly) has three classes of symbols for automatic spacing in math mode:

- unary operators like **cos** or **ln** (`\mathop`), which are followed by a thin skip (`\mskip\thinmuskip` or `\,`);
- binary operators like **+** or **×** (`\mathbin`) which are surrounded by medium skips (`\mskip\medmuskip` or `\:`);
- binary relations like **=** or **≤** (`\mathrel`) which are surrounded by thick skips (`\mskip\thickmuskip` or `\;`).

It has no special class for logical connectives, like **∧** or **∨**. Those are apparently considered binary operators. This sometimes makes sense, especially when writing *about* logic itself, and you are defining its grammar, or you are considering abstract formulas like *P*∧*Q*. However, I find it unsuitable when working *with* logic (which, at least for me, is much more frequent), and connecting concrete, large formulas. Consider for instance typesetting the formula 0 ≤ *i* ∧ *i* < *n*:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ 0 \leq i          \land        i < n \] % spacing of an operator (default)
\[ 0 \leq i \mathrel{\land}       i < n \] % spacing of a relation
\[ 0 \leq i   \;\;\;{\land}\;\;\; i < n \] % thrice the spacing of a relation
\end{document}
```

[image: different spacings for \land (LaTeX rendering)]

I find the first two renderings hard to read (and with the default settings, the difference between them is too subtle for my taste). Besides, The first one (certainly) and the second one (arguably) are also *conceptually* wrong, as they break the hierarchy:

1. operators (building larger expressions),
2. relations (building atomic formulas about expressions),
3. connectives (building larger formulas).

So for instance the first one would be read as 0 ≤ (*i*∧*i*) < *n*. For the formula to become readable enough to my eye, I found, it takes no less than three times as much spacing as for a relation.

## What I tried

To work around this, the best I have come up with is:

```tex
% creates a length akin to \thinmuskip, \medmuskip, \thickmuskip, for logical connectives:
\newmuskip \verythickmuskip
\verythickmuskip = 3\thickmuskip % default value (for instance)

% provide a command akin to \mathop, \mathbin, \mathrel, for logical connectives:
\newcommand \verythickspace {\mskip\verythickmuskip}
\newcommand \mathlop[1] {\verythickspace#1\verythickspace}

% define large-spacing logical connectives, using capitalized names
% (we rather not override the existing names as it breaks many things):
\newcommand \ANDop {\mathord{\land}}
\newcommand \AND   {\mathlop{\ANDop}}
\newcommand \ORop {\mathord{\lor}}
\newcommand \OR   {\mathlop{\ORop}}
% etc.
```

The issue it that `\mathlop{…}` only poorly mimicks the builtin symbol classes. It brutally adds space around the symbol regardless of the context, so spacing is not handled as with builtin classes. None of these work as one would expect: `{\AND}` (to disable spacing), `{}\AND{}` (to force spacing), etc. The class cannot be changed again by applying `\mathbin`, `\mathord` and the like; in particular, one cannot get just the symbol back without spacing around.

## Question

Is there a better way to do this? Can `\mathlop` be better implemented? Does some package already provide macros for logical connectives with large spacing?

I see that package amsmath simply defines `\implies` as `\;\Longrightarrow\;` so maybe there is no better solution indeed…